# Confusion on jasmine / Angular Test syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, jasmine

I am starting out with Angular and Jasmin tests and following the angular tutorial and this code is set for the test:

```
describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){

  beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

  it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller) {
    var scope = {},
        ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope:scope});

    expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);   }));

});
```

I am confused by this line:

```
var scope = {}, 
    ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope:scope});
```

1. How can a variable be set with a coma notation and what does this mean?
2. What does `{$scope:scope}` do? I can see it kind of binds the local scope variable in the test to the scope of the controller, but specifically I can not work out what this code is doing and if the syntax is Angular specific or not.

many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question:

It simply allows declaring multiple variables at once:

```
var i = 0, j = 1;
```

is identical to

```
var i = 0;
var j = 1;
```

Regarding your second question:

It allows passing a dependency that should normally be injected by angular. In short, you're injecting a scope that you have created by yourself (and which is an empty object) to the controller, instead of letting angular create a scope and injecting it to the controller. That's useful to pass a well-known scope, or to pass a mock service instead of the real implementation of a service.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes the obvious needs pointing out and it has helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

JB Nizet's answer is spot on, but just to be *really* clear since you seem to be new at JS and Angular, here's the same example with annotated code and a different name for scope to illustrate why it's required for testing:

```
it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller) {
  // A variable localized to this 'it' function that 
  // you can use to test results from the controller
  var myTestScope = {};

  // $controller(...) instantiates the controller and passes (injects) values.
  // This is essentially what Angular does during the normal application execution.
  var ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', { $scope: myTestScope });

  // Now the controller been instantiated (executes its code).  During this execution 
  // a property called 'phones' has been added to its $scope. This means myTestScope
  // now contains this property and you can test its value.
  expect(myTestScope.phones.length).toBe(3);    
}));
```

Comment: Brilliant, thankyou. That has cleared it up for me. Just a mental block on this and it was stopping me moving on. Great way to explain it.